# Insert TextBox between strings

Tags: c#, string, textbox, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am writing an application to Windows Store, it will have exercises with questions which can be answered. I created a class `Question` where I have 2 variables `question` and `answer`.

Example of question:

```
Question q = new Question(
    "This is simple [1] of question. This is the [2]",
    new string[]
    {
        "sample",
        "end"
    });
```

What I want is to add questions to a grid view as a `TextBlock` with a question and a `TextBox` (the place where we will write the answer) in a place of `[1]` and `[2]`. So it would look like this:

```
<TextBox>
     <TextBlock> This is simple </TextBlock>
<TextBox/>

<TextBlock> of question. This is the </TextBlock><TextBox/>
```

I'm not sure if I'm right to do it to look like that. Can I create a method in the `Question` class which adds items to MainPage.xaml in the way I presented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should make your own `UserControl` to display questions. The point is to create controls (`TextBlock`/`TextBox`) dynamically in code behind and add them as children to the `WrapPanel`. I can't see simple only-XAML decision here.

XAML:

```
<UserControl <!--skipped--> >
    <WrapPanel x:Name="mainPanel">
    </WrapPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
partial class QuestionControl : UserControl
{
    public QuestionControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Question _question = null;
    public Question Question
    {
        get { return _question; }
        set
        {
            _question = value;
            UpdateUI();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateUI()
    {
        mainPanel.Children.Clear();

        if (this.Question != null)
        {
            List<FrameworkElement> controls = new List<FrameworkElement>();
            string[] questionSegments = // some code to split question here

            foreach (var qs in questionSegments)
            {
                controls.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = qs } );
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < this.Question.AnswerStrings.Length; i++)
            {
                string answer = this.Question.AnswerStrings[i];
                TextBox newTextBox = new TextBox();
                controls.Insert(i * 2 + 1, newTextBox); // inserting TextBoxes between TextBlocks
            }

            foreach (var control in controls)
            {
                mainPanel.Children.Add(control); // adding all the controls to the wrap panel
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @AlexSkiba. I just have to change `WrapPanel` to `StackPanel`, and it works perfectly.